# How to access member pointers in template functions

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
  pointer* p;
  template<class T> f(T a)
  {
    p->property()->doSomething(a); // doSomething is a template function
  }
};
```

Above won't compile, but I want to access the member pointer in the template function even though it's unsafe. The reason I want to do this is because 'p->property()->doSomething(a)' is actually really really long, and I'm tried of rewriting it (and I don't want to use #define). So, how do I do something like that?

Edit: doSomething is a 3rd party function... but I think it is something like this:

```
template<class T>
void doSomething(T a)
{
  // something
}
```

Edit: here's the actual code:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QtWebKit>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply*);


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager *nam;
    QUrl _url;

    void outputHeader(QNetworkReply*);

    template<class T> void writeToOuput(T arg)
    {
        ui->textEdit->append(QString("%1").arg(arg));
    }
};
```

Edit: Here's the error I'm getting: 'invalid use of incomplete type ui::MainWindow'
When I click it, it goes to this line 'ui->textEdit->append(QString("%1").arg(arg));' in the code

Edit: Here's the other error: 'Forward declaration of Ui::MainWindow'
When I click it, it goes no where.

Comment: Please include the definition of `doSomething` and its container `class`, as well as the compiler output.

Comment: There is not enough information to know why this is wrong! Provided the type pointer has a method property that returns a pointer to an object with a doSomething method that accepts an object of type T as argument, there is nothing wrong. But I suspect this is not the case ... Please, provide a full sample of what doesn't compile!

Comment: The question is confused: first it says "*Above won't compile*", then it says "*because 'p->property()->doSomething(a)' is actually really really long, and I'm tried of rewriting it*" as if it works and he just want to make it realy really short so that he doesn't get tired writing this again and again.

Comment: and then...."*but I think it is something like this*".. you think? You don't **know** what it is?

Comment: I only know how to use the 3rd party function

Comment: Now, what is the question? State your question properly, and state the problem (which you're facing) also!

Comment: I am confused. Is `doSomething` a function or a **member** function? You call it as if it was a member function of whatever is returned by `property()`.

Comment: property() returns a object with a doSomething method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way the question is worded as is right now, I'm really having trouble making out what the problem is. However, if this is the code giving you trouble:

```
template<class T> void writeToOuput(T arg)
{
    ui->textEdit->append(QString("%1").arg(arg));
}
```

1. Try including `<QTextEdit>`
2. Does `Ui::MainWindow` actually define a member called `textEdit`?

It'd help if you could post the build error.

And finally, just a suggestion, but I'd recommend moving this to your cpp file as a non-member function:

```
template<class T> void writeToOuput(Ui::MainWindow* ui, T arg)
{
    ui->textEdit->append(QString("%1").arg(arg));
}
```

Rationale:

1. Less compile-time dependencies, faster builds.
2. Decouples the logic from your class as it does not need to be a member to function correctly.

Update: op posted the error.

> Edit: Here's the error I'm getting: 'invalid use of incomplete type
>   ui::MainWindow'

You need to include the header that defines ui::MainWindow instead of just working with a forward declaration. For MOC-generated files like this, that's generally going to be called ui_MainWindow.h.

Comment: @user1217419 I saw the update with the error you posted. I posted an update in the answer with a fix for that error.

Comment: You got it right. Now, i'm getting another error, but I'm going to try to fix this one on my own

Answer (score 1):

I think this part:

```
template<class T> void writeToOuput(T arg)
{
    ui->textEdit->append(QString("%1").arg(arg));
}
```

needs to be:

```
template<class T> void writeToOuput(T arg)
{
    ui->textEdit->append(arg);
}
```

and you need to provide missing conversion operators from a type T to QString.

Comment: +1 for catching the potential requirement for missing conversion operators. I think QString("%1").arg(arg) should be okay even though it's superfluous and wasteful and rather confusing given the fact that the method has the same name as the argument.

Comment: This 'QString("%1").arg(arg)' converts arg to QString, and QString("%1").arg(T a) is a template function

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not related to templates at all!
The compiler message says that:

- you forward-declared `Ui::MainWindow`
- you did not provide the implementation of `Ui::MainWindow` yet
- you tried to dereference the pointer to `Ui::MainWindow` -- that triggers an error

You have to provide the definition of `Ui::MainWindow` and only later provide the implementation of `::MainWindow::writeToOutput<T>(T arg)`.

If you cannot put definition of `Ui::MainWindow` before the definition of `::MainWindow`, you have to just declare the `writeToOutput<T>` here (without an implementation) and then provide the implementation later. Do note that template functions should better be declared as inlined (linkers can do strange things with those) and their implementation visible to all compilants that use it.

To define a previously declared member function you will need to put something like this:

```
template <class T>
inline void MainWindow::writeToOuput(T arg) {
    //your body
}
```

Comment: I would, but I don't have enough rep